# Installed WampServer 3.1.1 in separate folder from WampServer 2.1, but old dev environment now broken

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I tried to install WampServer 3.1.1 in a different folder from WampServer 2.1 but now I can't access my old dev environment anymore. None of the old aliases work anymore, and I have no idea how to find my old MySQL database to port over to the new environment, if it even exists anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can install the 32bit and 64bit WAMPServer on the same machine but not 2 versions of the 32bit or 2 version of the 64bit.

The reason being that the services from the new install will overwrite the existing services.

The service names are:

```
             32bit          64bit
Apache     wampapache     wampapache64
MySQL      wampmysqld     wampmysqld64
```

So you see, a 32 bit and a 64 bit WAMPServer (or rather its apache and mysql services) can co-exist. **As long as you dont try to start them both at the same time**. As MySQL will expect to use port 3306 and Apache will expect to use port 80.

Now to your issue. You can get around this and get back to your WAMPServer2.1 state as follows.

- Using the new WAMPServer you have installed do

  ```
  wampmanager->Apache->Services Administration->Stop Service
  wampmanager->Apache->Services Administration->Remove Service

  wampmanager->MySQL->Services Administration->Stop Service
  wampmanager->MySQL->Services Administration->Remove Service
  ```
- Exit any running WAMPSevers [wampmanager->exit]

  You now have no wampservers installed
- Run `\oldwamp\wampmanager.exe` (probably from filemanager)
- Using the menus on wampmanager.exe do:

  ```
  wampmanager->Apache->Services->Install Service
  wampmanager->Apache->Services->Start Resume Service

  wampmanager->MySQL->Services->Install Service
  wampmanager->MySQL->Services->Start Resume Service
  ```

  This should make the old Apache and MySQL the currently installed services
- Dump ALL your databases. Thats yours only, not the ones that come with MySQL. So not the databases called `mysql` or `information_schema` or `performance_schema`
  Put these backups somewhere safe!

Now, all you do is reverse the process to get the new Apache and MySQL services activated.

- So with the old WAMPServer running:

  ```
  wampmanager->Apache->Services->Stop Service
  wampmanager->Apache->Services->Remove Service

  wampmanager->MySQL->Services->Stop Service
  wampmanager->MySQL->Services->Remove Service

  wampmanager->exit
  ```

  Now it should be like you have No WAMPServer installed, so we need to re-activate the new WAMPServer3.1.1, so do this
- Run `\NEWwamp\wampmanager.exe` (probably from filemanager)
- Using the menus on wampmanager.exe do:

  ```
  wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration->Install Service
  wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration-> Start/Resume Service

  wampmanager->MySQL->Service Administration->Install Service
  wampmanager->MySQL->Service Administration->Start/Resume Service
  ```

Now the new Apache and MySQL should be running

- Now you can restore your database backups into your new MySQL server using `phpMyAdmin` or whatever tool you use.

Now to redo your Aliases, just copy each relevant Alias form `\oldwamp\alias` to `newwamp\alias` and EDIT each file to make sure Paths are correct for your new installations folder names.

You can do the same for any Virtual Hosts that you may have had. They will be in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache<oldversionnumber>\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Copying over the webiste code should be as simple as copying the folders from the old locations to a similar place in the new install.